# Autofac: Missing Method Involving MvvmLight RelayCommand

Tags: wpf, autofac, mvvm-light

I have a generic collection class based on the MvvM Light library which I've registered with Autofac:

```
public class DialogCollection<TViewModel> : ObservableCollection<TViewModel>, IDialogCollection<TViewModel> 
{
    private readonly IUIManager _uiManager;

    public DialogCollection( IUIManager uiManager )
    {
        _uiManager = uiManager ?? throw new NullReferenceException( nameof(uiManager) );

        ViewModelSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand<TViewModel>( DetailItemSelectedHandler );
        AddNewViewModelCommand = new RelayCommand( AddNewItemHandler );
    }

    public RelayCommand<TViewModel> ViewModelSelectedCommand { get; }
    public RelayCommand AddNewViewModelCommand { get; }
}
```

Autofac registration:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric( typeof(DialogCollection<>) )
    .As( typeof(IDialogCollection<>) );
```

IUIManager, the only argument to the DialogCollection constructor, is also registered with Autofac, and is properly instantiated when the program runs.

The specific instance of IDialogCollection is generated from a lambda method created by Autofac, which is passed in thru the constructor of a class which holds an instance of the collection I want to create:

```
public class CommunitiesModel
{
    private readonly Func<IDialogCollection<CommunityModel>> _colBuilder;
    private readonly Func<CommunityModel> _communityBuilder;

    private DialogCollection<CommunityModel> _communities;

    public CommunitiesModel( 
        Func<IDialogCollection<CommunityModel>> colBuilder,
        Func<CommunityModel> commmunityBuilder
        )
    {
        _colBuilder = colBuilder ?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(colBuilder));
        _communityBuilder= commmunityBuilder?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(commmunityBuilder));
    }

    // I'm not showing how Load() gets called, but it does :)
    public override void Load()
    {
        // this next line creates an instance of DialogCollection
        // it's also where the Autofac Missing Method exception gets thrown
        Communities = (DialogCollection<CommunityModel>) _colBuilder();
    }
}
```

Both colBuilder and communityBuilder are properly instantiated when passed into the CommunitiesModel constructor, which I presume means Autofac was able to use the registration information to create methods that create instances of those classes.

I don't understand why there's a missing method exception when _colBuilder() is executed, since the code compiles fine (meaning the RelayCommand ctor is known and available).

If I comment out the two RelayCommand creation lines (i.e., "new RelayCommand...") in the definition of DialogCollection<>, the exception is not thrown.

Which means the Autofac creator method is gacking on not finding something inside a constructor which has already been called with the appropriate constructur arguments.

Here is the exception that gets thrown:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException   HResult=0x80131500
>   Message=An error occurred during the activation of a particular
>   registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration:
>   Activator = DialogCollection`1 (ReflectionActivator), 
>   Services =[WpfFramework.IDialogCollection`1[[Olbert.CommunityScanner.Manager.ViewModel.CommunityModel,
>   CommunityScannerManager, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]], Lifetime =
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership
>   = OwnedByLifetimeScope   Source=Autofac   StackTrace:    at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)    at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
>
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Olbert.CommunityScanner.Manager.ViewModel.CommunitiesModel.Load() in
>   C:\Programming\CommunityScanner\CommunityScannerManager\ViewModel\CommunitiesModel.cs:line
>   58    at
>   Olbert.CommunityScanner.Manager.ViewModel.AppStateModel.set_ActivePageInfo(PageInfo
>   value) in
>   C:\Programming\CommunityScanner\CommunityScannerManager\ViewModel\AppWide\AppStateModel.cs:line
>   117    at
>   Olbert.CommunityScanner.Manager.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Programming\CommunityScanner\CommunityScannerManager\App.xaml.cs:line
>   44    at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
>   state)    at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object
>   obj)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 954
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 901
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 890
>   at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run()    at
>   Olbert.CommunityScanner.Manager.App.Main()
>
> Inner Exception 1: DependencyResolutionException: An exception was
>   thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(WpfFramework.IUIManager)' on type 'DialogCollection`1'.
>
> Inner Exception 2: MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void
>   GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand`1..ctor(System.Action`1)'.

I can provide more details if needed; what I've shown here is abstracted from a larger code base, but hopefully shows the relevant details.

Comment: `..ctor` is the static constructor on RelayCommand1.

Comment: Thanx, @Travis. Why would that method be missing given that the code compiles?

Comment: Sorry, mobile view bad, exception message very poorly formatted. Hard to say if it's static or instance ctor. Point is, find RelayCommand1. If there's no ctor that takes an Action, there you go. Work bottom up on this. The Autofac part is red herring. Meat of the issue is the inner exception at the bottom.

Comment: @TravisIllig, if you'll post your suggestion as an answer I'll accept it, because it put me on the right track to solving the problem. Thanx for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at `RelayCommand1` - it appears `IUIManager` or `DialogCollection<T>` needs that constructor and it's not there. Work bottom up on this. The Autofac part is red herring. Meat of the issue is the inner exception at the bottom.

Comment: Thanx, @TravisIllig. For anyone else encountering a similar error, mine was caused by a versioning problem involving the MvvmLight library. When I extracted a bunch of code into a separate assembly, I referenced MvvmLight in that new assembly...but forgot to check that nuget had installed the latest version of MvvmLight. It hadn't, and that was the source of the problem.

Comment: @MarkOlbert: Thanks, you should definitely post that as your own answer, that solved the issue in my case too